# Java Scanner cannot read words with accent mark

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have  problem with my CODE. IF I add words with accent mark to file, Scanner won´t read it.Thank you for help.

For example if file "names.txt" contains:
John
Lil
None

number of words in file is 3

but if contains:
Jóhn
Lil
None

number of words in file is 0

CODE IS:

```
    File file=new File("names.txt");
    Scanner skener=new Scanner(file);


    int count=0;

    while(skener.hasNext()){

        aArrayListOfNames.add(skener.next());
        count++;
    }

    skener.close();
    System.out.println("Count is "+count);
    return count;
```

Thank you all, problem FIXED! :D

Comment: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File, java.lang.String)`

Comment: user encoding like UTF-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844845/reading-file-with-accented-characters-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct the Scanner by defining the charset it should use:

```
Scanner skener=new Scanner(file,"UTF-8");
```

I believe ASCII is the default charset for Scanner so that needs to be changed. Also the file might not be encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get your error but it worked for me...

```
private static void getStrings() throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\XXX\\workspace\\stackoverflowtest1\\src\\stackoverflowtest1\\names.txt");
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(file);

    int count = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        nameArray.add(scanner.next());
        count++;
    }

    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("Count is " + count);
    System.out.println("1 - " + nameArray.get(0));
    System.out.println("2 - " + nameArray.get(1));
    System.out.println("3 - " + nameArray.get(2));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Count is 3
1 - Jóhn
2 - Lil
3 - None
```